# Как работает асинхронный пинг из примера Boost.Asio?

Tags: c++, boost, асинхронность, ping, asio

Взял [отсюда](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/icmp/ping.cpp) пример выполнения пинга по типу стандартной команды в Linux. Не могу в этом коде понять одно:

Как видно, код зациклен через вызов двух обработчиков, один из которых вызывается через таймер. Обработчики, в свою очередь, вызывают метод, асинхронно (отложенно) вызывающий этот обработчик.

К тому как работает цикл `start_receive + handle_receive` вопросов нет, все понятно. Проблема в том, что внутри `handle_receive` должна произойти отмена вызова `handle_timeout` через таймер. А значит, в свою очередь, не должен быть повторно запущен `start_send`. Вызов `timer_.cancel();` точно происходит (проверял).

Получается, что цикл `start_send + handle_timeout` должен разорваться при первом же получнном ответе. Но этого не происходит (код запускал). И я не могу понять почему. Как так получается?

Comment: там нет повторного старта, и не  нашел ни одного цикла. только рекурсивно прием ицмп

Comment: @eri, цикл реализованный через взаимный вызов. Я не думаю, что это рекурсия, т.к. нет вложенности самих вызовов.

Comment: @eri Тут вообще нет рекурсивных вызовов. Цикл крутит контекст в `run()`.

Comment: этот вызов только на прием. он не отправляет других пакетов.

Comment: @user7860670 разорванная через async_receive(bind, но по сути start_receive->handle_receive->start_receive та же рекурсия

Comment: @eri, это не рекурсия, как минимум потому, что стек при этом не увеличивается. На момент вызова каждой функции, предыдущая будет уже завершена.

Comment: @eri Нет, это не рекурсия. Тут следующий вызов `start_receive` будет происходить после того, как первый завершился. "разорванная" рекурсия - это уже как бы не рекурсия...

Comment: да это понятно. я о логической схеме. а не о коде. начал писать ответ - вроде разобрался -  теперь не понятно что там непонятного)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Этот пример составлен неправильно. Функция обратного вызова для передачи в `::boost::asio::basic_waitable_timer::async_wait` обязана принимать один аргумент с типом `::boost::system::error_code const &`. При вызове `timer_.cancel();` в этот обработчик будет передан `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted` в качестве кода ошибки. Обработчик обязан проверить код перед обработкой и не продолжать в случае получения ошибки.

Comment: Да понятно, что там код не идеален, это же просто пример. Если нормально писть, то там будут тысячи строк кода, и их будет невозможно читать тем, кто пытается разобраться с Asio.

Comment: @megorit он не "не идеален", он неправильный

Comment: Ну что тут скажешь, автор Asio написал неправильынй код с использованием Asio =)

Comment: @megorit Именно так. Хотя я подозреваю, что этот пример давно не обновлялся и в какой-то момент утратил работоспособность.

Comment: Мне главное понять, почему этот код работает, несмотря на то, что присходит вызов `steady_timer::cancel()`.

Comment: Он рабочий, по крайтей мере в том случае, если устройство пингуется.

Comment: @megorit Я как бы в ответе уже расписал почему `steady_timer::cancel()` оказывается бесполезным - потому что в обработчике игнорируется `boost::asio::error::operation_aborted`, который в него передается после вызова `steady_timer::cancel()`.

Comment: Но ведь обработчик вообще не должен быть вызван после вызова `steady_timer::cancel()`. Или я что-то не понимаю?

Comment: @megorit Нет, обработчик обязательно вызывается после вызова `steady_timer::cancel()`. https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_waitable_timer/cancel/overload1.html Но обработчик из примера просто не проверяет код ошибки и не в состоянии определить вызвался ли он по таймауту или из-за отмены.

Comment: Теперь понял) Спасибо. Странное поведение немного, конечно. Видимо, этот код и правда не должен был работать...

Comment: да нормальный код с нормальным поведением

Comment: и ничего не игнорируется событие cancel доходит до таймера и старт_сенд запускается снова

Answer (score 1):

```
timer_.async_wait(boost::bind(&pinger::start_send, this));
```

async_wait ждет любого события на таймере. Tут нет обработки operation_aborted или expired - [это задача колбэка (void on_timeout в доках)](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/deadline_timer.html#boost_asio.reference.deadline_timer.changing_an_active_deadline_timer_s_expiry_time), который запускает start_send в любом случае.